# Do I need mappings in elastic-search 6.0?

Tags: elasticsearch, mappings

Why do I need to make these "mappings" for elastic-search?

If I need them, how do I make these "mappings"?

I'm using elastic 6.0 on mac with logstash and kibana.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understand right - you asking about [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html)

From your question it impossible to understand what the core of your problem, and why this question is asked, but in short:

No, you don't need to define mappings if you don't know what the mappings does.
ElasticSearch have [Dynamic Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#_dynamic_mapping):

> "new field names will be added automatically, just by indexing a document."